# Transforming XML to HTML using Powershell .Net method

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, xslt

I am trying to transform an [XML file with an XSL file](https://ufile.io/f/0bohi) using Powershell .Net method. Here's my code,

```ps
#-- Create transformation --#
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform

#-- Create a reader with DTDparsing set to parse --#
$xrs = New-Object System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
$xrs.DtdProcessing = 'Parse'

#-- Load the XSL transform with the reader setting --#
$xr = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create("C:\Users\admin\Downloads\recoveryHistory_en.xsl", $xrs)
$xslt.Load($xr)

#-- Create a writer --#
$xws = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xw = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Test RP_failover.html", $xslt.OutputSettings)

#-- Execute the transform and output the results to a file --#
$xslt.Transform("C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Test RP_failover.xml", $xw)
$xw.Close()
```

Although the `$xslt.Transform()` did create the HTML file as intended, it appears to be totally empty. Here are the `xsl:output` and `xsl:choose` elements in the xsl file. My XML and XSL files are stored in the link above. I wonder if the `xsl:choose` element in the XSL file is causing the output HTML file to be empty as the XSL has `<xsl:when test="@outputType = 'csv'">` as well.

```xml
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>

<xsl:template match="RecoveryPlanStepReport">
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="@outputType = 'html'">
      <xsl:call-template name="PrintRecoveryPlanStepReportForHtml"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="@outputType = 'csv'">
      <xsl:call-template name="PrintRecoveryPlanStepReportForCsv"/>
   </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a value in the `Transform` property of `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` I could set to invoke `<xsl:when test="@outputType = 'html'">` explicitly? I'm trying to find out a way to force the XSL to use only HTML.

```ps
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$xslt.Transform.Value
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Transform(System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable input, System.Xml.XmlWriter results)
void Transform(System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.Xml.XmlWriter results)
void Transform(System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.IO.TextWriter results)
void Transform(System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.IO.Stream results)
void Transform(System.Xml.XmlReader input, System.Xml.XmlWriter results)
void Transform(System.Xml.XmlReader input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.Xml.XmlWriter results)
void Transform(System.Xml.XmlReader input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.IO.TextWriter results)
void Transform(System.Xml.XmlReader input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.IO.Stream results)
void Transform(string inputUri, System.Xml.XmlWriter results)
void Transform(string inputUri, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.Xml.XmlWriter results)
void Transform(string inputUri, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.IO.TextWriter results)
void Transform(string inputUri, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.IO.Stream results)
void Transform(string inputUri, string resultsFile)
void Transform(System.Xml.XmlReader input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.Xml.XmlWriter results, System.Xml.XmlResolver documentResolver)
void Transform(System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable input, System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList arguments, System.Xml.XmlWriter results, System.Xml.XmlResolver documentResolver)
```

Comment: Is the XSLT working against that XML in another context like an IDE or XML editor or when run with the command line API of an XSLT processor? Otherwise, more than 90% of those problems that an XSLT doesn't output any data is simply a default namespace in the XML input that the XSLT doesn't take into account. So you would need to show the relevant parts of XML and XSLT, we can't tell why a template fails without seeing the relevant XML input.

Comment: I'm with Martin Honnen in this. Just run an identity transformation like `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>` so you can test the common namespace issue.

Comment: Sorry if it my message wasn't clear enough. I've uploaded my XML and XSL files to https://ufile.io/f/0bohi and linked it above in the original question. I thought it'd be wise to store them there instead of pasting the entire content, which I thought would be difficult to read. Let me test with a couple of online XSLT/XML validators and see what happens.

Comment: @Alejandro, it was your hint that fixed it. There was a problem with the ```<xsl:when test=EXPRESSION>``` where the expression did not exist in the XML, therefore the ```<xsl:call-template name="PrintHistoryReportForHtml"/>``` was not called. Moreover, I had to remove all the templates related to CSV. Now I'm able to generate the HTML file successfully with the modified XSLT. Thank you very much. If you could post your comment as answer, I can mark it as "Answer".

Comment: Try to reduce samples to a minimum to demonstrate the problem and insert the relevant parts inline. If you want to put samples online as well then at least use a side we can browse to to see the source, not one offering downloads.

Comment: @joso You can also answer your own question. I didn't see your samples, thus I cannot answer.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, sure I understand your point. There are many features in the stackoverflow I'm not aware of. By the way, sorry I don't understand what you mean by "use a side" to browse the source code and I don't know how to do that. Thanks for your time on this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it,

I modified the below snippet in the **XSL** from this

```
   <xsl:template match="RecoveryPlanResult">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="Results">  <!-- SRM 4.x identifying tag -->
         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="@outputType = 'html'">
             <xsl:call-template name="LegacyPrintHistoryReportForHtml"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="@outputType = 'csv'">
             <xsl:call-template name="LegacyPrintHistoryReportForCsv"/>
           </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>  <!-- SRM 5.x -->
         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="@outputType = 'html'">
             <xsl:call-template name="PrintHistoryReportForHtml"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="@outputType = 'csv'">
             <xsl:call-template name="PrintHistoryReportForCsv"/>
           </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

to this

```
<xsl:template match="RecoveryPlanResult">
    <xsl:call-template name="PrintHistoryReportForHtml"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Problem:** Although the `match` element had the correct pattern in the `xsl:template` element, the expression in the `xsl:when` element was incorrect

```
<xsl:when test="@outputType = 'html'">
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecoveryPlanResult>
  <RecoveryPlan>
    <Name>Test RP</Name>
    <Description />
    <LocalVcAddress>LocalVC</LocalVcAddress>
    <LocalSiteName>LocalSite</LocalSiteName>
    <RemoteVcAddress>remote</RemoteVcAddress>
    <RemoteSiteName>remote</RemoteSiteName>
    <TimeZoneOffset>0</TimeZoneOffset>
  </RecoveryPlan>
</RecoveryPlanResult>
```